# Proportional progression with limit.

Tags: sequences-and-series

In fact my problem more about finding the name of the Math topic that I have to study to solve my real problem. I'm going to explain it so maybe you can help me.
I have an area of 100cm. Inside this area I have 10 same sized divisions of 10cm. What I want is change the way that the size of these divisions is distributed in an incremental and proportional way.

I have these two images that can give more information about the problem.

This is what I have today:

[image]

This is where I want to go:

[image]

Do someone a formula where I can do this distribution? Thanks!

Comment: What is the relationship between the widths/heights of neighbouring columns e.g is column 2 width = 90% of column 1 width and row 2 height = 90% of row 1 height? something like that??

Answer (score 0):

Try making an arithmetic series
http://www.mathwords.com/a/arithmetic_sequence.htm
I would try a limit as t goes from 1 to 0.
You have 10 values that vary a1, a2, ... a10.
When t is 1, they all equal 10.
When t is 0, a1 is 100, and all the rest are 0.

let sum = 1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4 ... + 1/10.
sum ~ 2.92897.

Here is an approximation.
When t is 0.5, a1 is 50, a2 is 25, a3 is 50/3, a4 is 50/4 and a10 is 50/10.
The problem with the approximation is when I add them together, I get 50*sum.
You may need do divide through by sum or something.

so my guess is 
a1 = 100 - 90*t
and
a10 is 100 - 99*(1-t)

I did not answer your problem, but hopefully I gave you a start.
Regards,
Matt